# Angular 6 route params reload after Location.go

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

In order to avoid any component reload I'm using `Location.go` to change the URL from my first Component (*SearchboxComponent*).

The thing is that I'm using the route params in a second Component (*ListingComponent*) to reflect the URL changes in some links, pagination etc. But the new URL is not detected by my subscription and the params don't change. Can I make the router module reparse the URL to fill the new params?

ListingComponent

```
this.route.params.subscribe( async (params: IListingUrlParams) => {
    console.log('params', params);
});
```

SearchboxComponent

```
const url = this.parametersService.searchParamsToUrl(params);
// this.router.navigate([url]); This works but reloads my main component
this.listingsService.getList(params); // Fetch the new data before navigation
Location.go(url); // This works but params are not reloaded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to update your current route parameters.**

Lets say your route as:

> path/:id

**Current path : path/123**

in component:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) { }
    updateRoute(){
    let url = this.location.path().replace('123', '456');
      this.location.go(url);
    }
```

**Updated path : path/456**

Comment: So I need to manually reload every single parameter instead of re-parsing the whole URL?

Comment: you can match compete url as well. i have just taken a single parameter replace.,

Comment: its recommenced only for params not routes.